# Decrypting Bitcoin Core wallet with password that contains special characters

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery, encryption, mac

I have come across a Bitcoin Core wallet that uses a special character for the passphrase. When attempting to decrypt, it accepts the password but does not decrypt part of the keys.

Is there a known bug where core fails to decrypt key pairs using special non-standard characters?

This happens for Bitcoin Core version 0.19.1 for Mac 0SX.

Answer (score 3):

There have previously been issues with entering passphrases that contain non-ascii characters, however these all were related to how the terminal processes those characters before Bitcoin Core does.

If you are receiving an error message that says something along the lines of "Some keys decrypt but not all", then the wallet has been corrupted. There are no known issues that would cause that other than wallet corruption.